# Can i use the below to unset several sessions

Tags: php, session, unset

I have several sessions like this:

```
$_SESSION['search']['max']
$_SESSION['search']['order']
```

Currently, I unset each one of them with a separate statement:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['search']['max']) && $_SESSION['search']['max'] != ''){
        unset($_SESSION['search']['max']);
    }
if(isset($_SESSION['search']['order']) && $_SESSION['search']['order'] != ''){
        unset($_SESSION['search']['order']);
    }
```

My question is - can I use the below general unset statement instead of having a separate statement for each session:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['search']) && $_SESSION['search'] != ''){
            unset($_SESSION['search']);
        }
```

Are there any advantages of declaring each unset statement separately?

Note: I need to unset them all at the same time, meaning I do not need to keep one or more to use again, therefore I believe one statement should do but need to be sure I am not missing out anything.

Thank you all!

Comment: Yes you can use this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have several sessions like this:

Nope. You have one session. Those are just variables.

> My question is - can I use the below general unset statement instead of having a separate statement for each <strike>session</strike> variable:
>
> ```
>   if(isset($_SESSION['search']) && $_SESSION['search'] != ''){
>         unset($_SESSION['search']);
>     }
> ```

You can. It's just normal array. And `unset($a)` is the same as `$a = null`, so your code is just:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['search']) && $_SESSION['search'] != ''){
    $_SESSION['search'] = null;
}
```

Meaning that **every** element of `$_SESSION['search']` array will be discarded.

**HOWEVER** you are **not** unsetting session!
Your session is still live, you just discard some of variables inside the session!

> Are there any advantages of declaring each unset statement separately?

There is. You have control of which variables stay (like, "I want A and B to stay, but unset C and D"). But if you are like "nah, I'm sure I don't need any of them", then you can just unset them in a bulk and there is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Now I definitely know more than before!